# Permutations and Combinations,Linear/Circular arrangement

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can
36 people  be seated on a square table , 9 on each side?

Assume the same thing that is done in a circle.i.e It has corners else same circular order is 1 permutation only.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I tried thinking of it as a linear and circular arrangement mix.But since number of people is too much I CANNOT make individual cases.

Comment: First are the sides of the table different?

Comment: Assume the same thing that is done in a circle.i.e It has corners else same circular order is 1 permutation only.

Comment: @AJ_ Make it a custom to say things like that in your question allready. Not in a comment afterwards. In the first place as information and in the second place to make people more willing to help.

Comment: If the sides are different, just pick who sits in each side, and then permutate over those picks

Comment: Sides are not different in the sense that same clockwise order is counted only once.

Comment: If you fill side by side, in how many ways can you fill the first side?

Comment: 36P9 if you talk about the first side.

Comment: @AJ_ if the sides are not different, then permutate them all, and then divide by the simillar cases, for example the same pemutation with a cyclic shift right of 9 spots.

Comment: Yep, and the second, and … In the end, you will have overcounted because you ignored rotations of the table. Taking account of that should be a matter of a simple division.

Comment: The confusing part here is the corners.

Answer (score 0):

Let's fill side by side :
First side : $\binom{36}{9}$
Second side : $\binom{27}{9}$
Third side : $\binom{18}{9}$
Last side : $1$

And each side can be permutted so each side got a factor $9!$

But know we need now to take in account that we just consider the order.
So for example $(a;b;c;d)=(b;c;d;a)$ but $(a;b;c;d) \ne (a;c;b;d)$
So each solution has been count 4 times.

In conclusion :
$$ \frac{(9!)^4 * \binom{36}{9}*\binom{27}{9}*\binom{18}{9}}{4} $$

Answer (score 0):

For $\bf n$-sided polygon $\bf (n\le36)$:
$$A(n)\frac{36!}n$$
For Square:
$$A(4)=\frac{36!}{4}\approx9.299\times10^{40}\sim9.3\times10^{40}$$
For circle (note that circle **"here"** is a $\bf 36-$sided polygon):
$$A(36)=\frac{36!}{36}\approx1.0333\times10^{40}\sim1.0\times10^{40}$$

---

**Note:** $$\frac{9!^4\binom{36}{9}\binom{27}{9}\binom{18}{9}}{4}=\frac{36!}4$$